# Eclipse. Restore project ".settings" directory

Tags: java, eclipse

Accidentally I delete project  ".settings" folder from directory where located Java project. 
In this directory were located files like:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
```

etc..

Can I restore them? Now eclipse show error when methods marked with `@Override` annotation (Eclipse don't understand that I implement some interfaces). It is not full list of errors.

Thanks!

Comment: No way to restore them, unless in a non-Eclipse-specific way. Like, I keep those checked into my VCS. Or an OS-level undelete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a backup or generating your Eclipse project settings from some build system  you should manually set your project preferences again in Eclipse (open project properties and look through the settings).
E,g, the problem with annotations is incorrect Java version setting for compiler (you need java 1.6 or higher).

Maybe your project is very simple then you may create new project with appropriate settings and copy your sources from broken project to new one.

If you want to avoid similar situation with workspace settings you may export them and backup resulting file (see file/export/general/preferences).

It is usually very convenient to generate Eclipse project from build configuration (e.g. all Maven, Gradle, Leiningen can do this). This works well unless you need some specific settings in Eclipse project that are not yet supported by build system.

Comment: this good point if you have it! especially gradle! And you think about backup after incident. "copy your sources from broken project to new one" sometimes has troubles too.

Answer (score 2):

i also had faced this issue once upon a time.
there is a solution for this.

```
    Just delete the project from Eclipse workspace and import it again.
    the settings will be created for the project.
```

> Note: Don't delete it from Disk(it will ask for that when you try to
>   delete,so don't check the checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

It's needs lots of time. You should delete all eclipse files and import/create again this project. One time I have had some problem and I spent 3 hours for restoring. I tried restore using hdd recovery tools then manually checked some parameters. But in result I didn't fix all problems because in my case files was damaged.